# No text returned for IWebElement.Text

Tags: c#, html, selenium, xpath

I have some xpath which correctly returns me the nodes I am after but I cannot retrieve the text between the  tags in Selenium.

The below correctly returns the 4 nodes I am after:

```
var subMenuItems = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@id='OpenandApply123']//a"));
```

However when I do the below I get nothing for text returned when I'm expecting "abc123":

```
string item1 = subMenuItems[0].Text;
```

How do I get the texts for abc123, def123 etc, returned?

Full html below, apologies for formatting:

```
<div class="subMenu" id="OpenandApply123" role="menu" aria-hidden="false" style="" xpath="1">
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="150" role="presentation">

                                    <tbody><tr role="presentation">
                                        <td role="presentation" class="">
                                            <a id="abc.feature_link" href="abc/abc" class="menuItem" target="_top" style="background-position: 4px 2px;">
                                                abc123
                                            </a>


                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr role="presentation">
                                        <td role="presentation" class="">
                                            <a id="def.feature_link" href="abc/Feature/def" class="menuItem" target="_top" style="background-position: 4px 2px;">
                                                def123
                                            </a>


                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr role="presentation">
                                        <td role="presentation">
                                            <a id="ghi.feature_link" href="abc/Feature/ghi" class="menuItem" target="_top" style="">
                                                ghi123
                                            </a>


                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr role="presentation">
                                        <td role="presentation">
                                            <a id="klm.feature_link" href="abc/klm" class="menuItem" target="_top" style="">
                                                klm123
                                            </a>


                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                            </tbody></table>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest induce `WebDriverWait` and wait for `VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy`() and following xpath.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.XPath("//td[@role='presentation']//a")));
var subMenuItems = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//td[@role='presentation']//a"));
string item1 = subMenuItems[0].Text;
```

Or

```
string item1 = subMenuItems[0].GetAttribute("textContent");
```

Comment: Thanks for your post. Can you please explain why in this context .Text does not work but .GetAttribute works? How did you know to use GetAttribute when there are no explicit attributes?

Comment: When the text is not visible `.Text ` won't work in those case.However `GetAttribute("textContent")` will work.

Comment: @ratsstack : you can check this link https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_textcontent.asp

Comment: @ratsstack : If this resolved your query please accept  and upvote this as an answer for clouser.Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation